# RavenDB Asp.Net Core - querying documents throws convert exception

Tags: c#, ravendb

I am using v5.1 of RavenDB client for C# (.Net 5 - the latest release). My ravendb server (ravendb/ravendb:5.1-ubuntu-latest) + app are running in linux docker containers.

On my app startup, I want to seed my ravendb instance with some data. I initialize the database if it does not exist, try to check existence of any entities, and seed the database if empty.

```
public async Task SeedIngredientsAsync()
        {
            //ensure database exists first
            await this.EnsureDatabaseExistsAsync();

            IngredientViewDto? existingIngredient = null;
  
            try
            {
                //below query throws exception
                existingIngredient = await _session.Query<IngredientViewDto>()
                                                   .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

                _logger.LogInformation($"Ingredient exist - {existingIngredient}");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new CreateDatabaseException($"Could not check if ingredient exists -{e.Message}");
            }

            if (existingIngredient == null)
            {
                BulkInsertOperation? bulkInsert = null;

                try
                {
                    _logger.LogError("Inserting ingredients...");

                    var ingredientsToInsert = this.GenerateIngredients();

                    bulkInsert = _session.Advanced.DocumentStore.BulkInsert(_session.Advanced.DocumentStore.Database);

                    for (int i = 0; i < ingredientsToInsert.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var ingredient = ingredientsToInsert[i];
                        await bulkInsert.StoreAsync(ingredient, ingredient.Id.ToString());
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw new CreateDatabaseException($"Could not seed view database - {e.Message}");
                }
                finally
                {
                    await _session.SaveChangesAsync();

                    if (bulkInsert != null)
                    {
                        await bulkInsert.DisposeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }

                    _logger.LogError("Ingredients inserted...");
                }
            }
        }
```

When I run above, I always get an exception when trying to query my entities within the db

> Could not convert document 6d19cb32-8597-4406-9fce-86505da62a6f to entity of type IngredientViewDto

My entity is a POCO:

```
public class IngredientViewDto
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public string Url{ get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public DateTimeOffset LastUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

I am using the linq extension method from the `Raven.Client.Documents` namespace. Their official docs also show the same setup for querying an object : [Docs](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.1/csharp/client-api/session/querying/how-to-query). Unsure what the issue is here. Am I missing any configuration that I am not seeing?

Comment: Id's are strings in RavenDB. Why are you declaring the Id property as Guid?

Comment: @JesúsLópez I glossed right over that. Changing it to a string fixed the issue. I was under the assumption that the client would auto parse the string value but that does not seem to be the case. Do you know if there is any issues with using string version of Guid instead of the default format Raven uses: collection/number-tag? Just want to ensure I am not making performance worse by supplying my own custom Id (i.e. Guid.ToString()).

Comment: Since guids are random, performance will suffer due to many page splits. I use guids, but I generate them sequentially using `RT.Comb.Provider.PostgreSql.Create().ToString("N")` I also prepend the collection name to the Id, something like this `Ingredients/<the stupid sequenciatl guid>` this allows me to perform some magic with `LoadStartingWith` when I use hierarchical Id's

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I might let Raven take care of Ids and have a separate field to capture entity Id in that case or go down the route you mentioned above. If you want to post an answer I can mark it as such.